# How to set focus on QMenu Item programmatically

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qmenu

What I want to do with this piece of code is set the focus on the `QMenu` Item programmatically. But neither `QMenu::setActiveAction()` nor `QMenu::popup()` works.
How can I do that?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QMenuBar>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow();

    window->setWindowTitle(QString::fromUtf8("Test:QMenu"));
    window->resize(336, 227);

    QAction *newAct = new QAction("&New",window);
    QAction *openAct = new QAction("&Open",window);
    QAction *saveAct = new QAction("&Save",window);

    QMenu *fileMenu;

    fileMenu = window->menuBar()->addMenu("&File");
    fileMenu->addAction(newAct);
    fileMenu->addAction(openAct);
    fileMenu->addAction(saveAct);

    window->show();

    fileMenu->popup(QPoint(10,10));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

QMenu items are not "focusable" in the same manner as other widgets. And, actually, they shouldn't, because what you want is not common practice of their usage.

As a workaround, on mouse press you can get mouse cursor position, pre-calculate offset of your default menu item in the popup menu and show the menu at the point, where mouse cursor underly your default menu item. This solution was suggested [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/24789).

Also, what will be more nice for user, to select default menu item you can generates narrow keys buttons events after you display your popup. This works on Windows, but not sure about other OS.

Comment: Actually the one of the software requirements is that only keyboard will be used as the user input device.In this regard your first suggetion does not help.And your second suggetion is not clear to me.it will be helpful if you explain this point

Comment: Try to press right mouse button to get popup menu in your browser. After menu is appeared, try to press up/down narrow keys on the keyboard. You will see, that selected menu item jumps, so you can generate press events grammatically to get needed item selected.